# Getting today's events from iCal with Applescript

Tags: applescript, icalendar

I iterate over all the events in iCal to get only today's events, but I don't think this is efficient. Is there a function/method to get only today's events?

```
tell application "iCal"
    tell calendar "Lotus Notes"
        set today to (current date)
        set this_year to year of today
        set this_month to month of today
        set this_day to day of today

        repeat with c in every event
            set d to start date of c
            set the_year to year of d
            set the_month to month of d
            set the_day to day of d
            if (the_year = this_year) and (the_month = this_month) and (the_day = this_day) then
                show c
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to current date
set str to (m as string) & " " & (d as string) & " " & (y as string)
set today to date str
set tomorrow to today + 60 * 60 * 24

tell application "iCal"
    tell calendar "Lotus Notes"
        set curr to every event whose start date is greater than or equal to today ¬
            and start date is less than or equal to tomorrow
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: This won't get any repeating events, first defined on an early date, that occur today. Looks like a tough problem and looking at other answers on SO, folks seem to be using http://hasseg.org/icalBuddy/